# Is it possible to 'PUT' data cross-domain with JQuery .ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

We try to put some data to our server, the serverside should be okay because we tested already with DEV HTTP CLIENT Chrome extension. This is our code, I think it should work but I don't know how I could fix the cross domain error.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '...../add?callback=JSONPCallback',
        contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "name": "Test",
        }),
        jsonpCallback: "JSONPCallback",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Success!');
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            console.error(a + " " + b + " " + c);
        },
        fail: function (e) {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
}
```

In the GET requests we used 'dataType: 'jsonp' ', but this is not working for PUT . Is there any possibility to PUT a json object and GET a jsonp object back in the success method?

Comment: `JSONP` can only send `GET` requests, by nature.

Comment: Well, but there must be a possibility to PUT data Cross-domain?

Comment: Yes, it's called [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: The presence of crossDomain changes the type to "GET".  I think "PUT" and jsonp are mutually exclusive.  So RESTful services must provide a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" whitelist (use CORS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONP is a `GET` operation (specifically, one created via a `script` tag).

You *can* do cross-domain `PUT`, just not in the JSONP way. Your target server has to allow your origin via [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (and your browser has to [support CORS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) with `XMLHttpRequest`, not the IE8 and IE9 `XDomainRequest` object — although if you need IE8 and IE9 support, if you look around you can find a plugin for jQuery that makes jQuery use `XDomainRequest` on those browsers).

Comment: So there is no possibility to do this with jquery?

Comment: @Thunder: Yes, you can do this with jQuery. Please read again. If you're using IE10+ or any modern non-IE browser, provided the server allows your origin, you can do it with jQuery's `$.ajax`. If you need to support IE8 or IE9, then you'll need a plugin that makes jQuery use their non-standard `XDomainRequest` rather than `XMLHttpRequest` under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using modern browser (i.e. Firefox and chrome, safari), you can use HTML5 API CORS for doing this.
Here is the link for [Using cors](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)